# VirtualBox virtual machine asks to install on hard drive even after it's already installed?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora

I installed a fedora machine with virtual box with the following settings:
[image: storage settings]

[image: general settings]

normally, it should be installed in fedora2.vdi (I already did "Install to hard drive" once), however when I start the machine it still asks me to install on hard drive:
[image: install hard drive]
[image: drive]

Is there something I forgot to click?

Thanks

Comment: Did you download the correct ISO?   I think you downloaded Live (for install on USB) and rather need the Full install ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that after installing the OS from the ISO you still left the ISO connected to the virtual machine, and it's the first in the boot order. So, every time you boot you still boot from the installation media instead of booting from the VDI hard drive.

You need to click on the ISO in Setting > Storage, and then on the option on the right to choose disk:
[image]
And in there choose to **Remove Disk**:
[image]
Then start the virtual machine and it should boot from the hard drive (VDI.)